# Is it possible to set condition for instance in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2

I looking for a way to skip instances while rendering in shader.
I have one million instances, and to achieve performance, based on current viewbox I will skip instances based on their boundings.

Is any place where I can write code for condition?

JS is slower than GPU, so I'm looking for how to make this condition in the GLSL

Answer (score 0):

you can't "Skip" an instance. You can move all of its vertices off the screen

```
attribute float visible;
...

  gl_Position = mix(vec4(0, 0, -2, 1), gl_Position, visible);
```

or something like that. If `visible` is 1.0 then you get the same as you've always gotten. If `visible` is 0.0 then all of its vertices are outside of clip space.

You could also pass in the bounds in some form (center + radius,  aabb) and effectively do the same thing. Compute if that center + radius is in the view frustum, if not set `gl_Position` to something outside clip space. Of course if they were going to be outside of clip space already then this isn't helping.

Still, a million instances is probably too many for most GPUs

Comment: When vertices are off the screen  does it reduce gpu load?

Comment: When all the vertices for a triangle are off the screen then that triangle is not drawn so yes. Drawing less pixels = less gpu load.